# how to make input elements symmetric size (equal width) in a bootstrap row

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create multiple input boxes in two columns. However, I cannot make the size of the boxes equal in each bootstrap row. Because I am not a web developer, any advice on how to resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated!

The reproducible example can be accessed from this [link](https://codepen.io/wasimaftab/pen/XWaLqdy)

```js
/* create single select box */
function createSingleSelectBox(id, header_arr) {
  var selectBox = document.createElement("select");
  selectBox.setAttribute("id", id);
  selectBox.multiple = false;
  selectBox.className = "input-small w-50";

  for (var i = 0; i < header_arr.length; i++) {
    var op = new Option();
    op.value = header_arr[i];
    op.text = header_arr[i];
    selectBox.options.add(op);
  }
  return selectBox;
}

/* create input number box */
function createInputNumberBox(id, min, step, type, my_class, default_val) {
  var inputNumBox = document.createElement("input");
  inputNumBox.id = id;
  inputNumBox.className = my_class;
  inputNumBox.type = type;
  inputNumBox.step = step;
  inputNumBox.min = min;
  inputNumBox.value = default_val;
  return inputNumBox;
}

/* create heading with icon*/
function createHeadingWithIcon(
  head_type,
  head_text,
  icon_id,
  bottom_margin_px
) {
  var h = document.createElement(head_type);
  h.innerHTML =
    head_text +
    " " +
    "<i class='far fa-question-circle' " +
    icon_id +
    " style='color:grey'></i>";
  // <i class="far fa-question-circle" id="go_tooltip" style="color:grey"></i>
  h.style.marginBottom = bottom_margin_px;
  return h;
}

//#######################################################################################################################

var h4 = createHeadingWithIcon("h6", "R1_C1", "id='exclusive_tooltip'", "5px");
document.getElementById("id_R1_C1").appendChild(h4);
var exclusive_all = ["YES", "NO"];
var single_selectbox = createSingleSelectBox("R1_C1_select", exclusive_all);
document.getElementById("id_R1_C1").appendChild(single_selectbox);

var h4 = createHeadingWithIcon("h6", "R1_C2", "id='k_out_N_tooltip'", "5px");
document.getElementById("id_R1_C2").appendChild(h4);
var inputNumBox = createInputNumberBox(
  "id_R1_C2_input",
  1,
  1,
  "number",
  "input-xs w-50 h-50",
  "2"
);
document.getElementById("id_R1_C2").appendChild(inputNumBox);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="card pl-2 py-2">
    <div class="card-block">
      <div class="row pl-2">
        <div class="col-md-7" id="id_R1_C1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-5" id="id_R1_C2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _I cannot make the size of the boxes equal in each bootstrap row._ Same length (horizontally)? Same height? Same value? What needs to be equal?

Comment: Same length horizontally i.e. equal width. I have edited the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two obvious problems here:

1. You've linked to [Bootstrap v3.3.5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/), but you're using [Bootstrap v5](https://getbootstrap.com/) classes. In particular, the `w-50` class wasn't available in v3.
2. You're specifying that the inputs should be `50%` of the width of their parent. But the parents are different widths - one is seven columns *(~58% of the container)*, and the other is five columns *(~42% of the container)*.

If you're able to update to Bootstrap v5, then you can make your inputs the same size with:

```js
/* create single select box */
function createSingleSelectBox(id, header_arr) {
  var selectBox = document.createElement("select");
  selectBox.setAttribute("id", id);
  selectBox.multiple = false;
  selectBox.className = "input-small w-50";

  for (var i = 0; i < header_arr.length; i++) {
    var op = new Option();
    op.value = header_arr[i];
    op.text = header_arr[i];
    selectBox.options.add(op);
  }
  return selectBox;
}

/* create input number box */
function createInputNumberBox(id, min, step, type, my_class, default_val) {
  var inputNumBox = document.createElement("input");
  inputNumBox.id = id;
  inputNumBox.className = my_class;
  inputNumBox.type = type;
  inputNumBox.step = step;
  inputNumBox.min = min;
  inputNumBox.value = default_val;
  return inputNumBox;
}

/* create heading with icon*/
function createHeadingWithIcon(
  head_type,
  head_text,
  icon_id,
  bottom_margin_px
) {
  var h = document.createElement(head_type);
  h.innerHTML =
    head_text +
    " " +
    "<i class='far fa-question-circle' " +
    icon_id +
    " style='color:grey'></i>";
  // <i class="far fa-question-circle" id="go_tooltip" style="color:grey"></i>
  h.style.marginBottom = bottom_margin_px;
  return h;
}

//#######################################################################################################################

var h4 = createHeadingWithIcon("h6", "R1_C1", "id='exclusive_tooltip'", "5px");
document.getElementById("id_R1_C1").appendChild(h4);
var exclusive_all = ["YES", "NO"];
var single_selectbox = createSingleSelectBox("R1_C1_select", exclusive_all);
document.getElementById("id_R1_C1").appendChild(single_selectbox);

var h4 = createHeadingWithIcon("h6", "R1_C2", "id='k_out_N_tooltip'", "5px");
document.getElementById("id_R1_C2").appendChild(h4);
var inputNumBox = createInputNumberBox(
  "id_R1_C2_input",
  1,
  1,
  "number",
  "input-xs w-50 h-50",
  "2"
);
document.getElementById("id_R1_C2").appendChild(inputNumBox);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="card pl-2 py-2">
    <div class="card-block">
      <div class="row pl-2">
        <div class="col-md-6" id="id_R1_C1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6" id="id_R1_C2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**NB:** There are a lot of changes between v3 and v5. If you're working with an existing site, changing Bootstrap versions is not a trivial task.

Comment: makes sense. thanks